# How can I print the result of File::Find on html perl script?

Tags: perl

I have to show the results from a search in a website. I'm receiving a search parameter from an html form. When I try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI qw(:standard);
use File::Find;
my $search = param('value');
my $result = `print find(sub {print $File::Find::name if ($_ eq $search);
}, '/home');`

print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";

print "<html>";
print "<head></head>";
print "<body";
print "$result";
print "</body>";
print "</html>";
```

I get the following error:

```
syntax error at ./search.pl line 8, near "print"
Execution of ./search.pl aborted due to complication errors.
```

I think it's the assigning of find that's prompting the error. But I've tried other ways to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is back tick. Back tick only using for execute the linux commands.

`print find(sub {print $File::Find::name if ($_ eq $search); }, '/home');`  This is not a linux command. This is perl script.

So your script should be as follow

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI qw(:standard);
use File::Find;
my $search = param('value');
my $result;
find( sub { $result.=$File::Find::name if ($_ eq $search ); }, "/home");

print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";

print "<html>";
print "<head></head>";
print "<body>";
print "$result\n\n";
print "</body>";
print "</html>";
```

You want to execute the result in back tick run the perl one liner with `-e` `-M` switches. `-e` to execute the perl command. `-M` switch using for include the module in you oneliner.  So which is should be as follow

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI qw(:standard);
my $search = param('value');
my $result = ` perl -MFile::Find -e 'print find(sub {print $File::Find::name if(/^$search\$/);}, "/home" )'`;

print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";

print "<html>";
print "<head></head>";
print "<body>";
print "$result";
print "</body>";
print "</html>";
```